# Speed optimization of shadow computation with grass gis r.sun

Tags: grass-gis, shadow

I am trying to optimize the speed of r.sun to compute shadowed area on a DTM at 1m resolution. My current area is 3.39 km² but my final area will be 450 km².

The [r.sun wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R.sun) say that pre-computing horizons as well as lat/lon increase the model, but the opposite happen on my computer (GRASS 7.0.1RC2, Windows7 64 bits [although r.sun run in 32 bits mode], 4 CPU, 8 threads)

Here is an example:

```bash
r.sun elevation=MNEcomplet@ShadowProject day=88 time=7 incidout=incidoutD88T07 --overwrite npartitions=2 distance_step=1
```

==> 38 sec

```bash
r.sun elevation=MNEcomplet@ShadowProject horizon_basename=horizon horizon_step=30 day=88 time=7 incidout=incidoutD88T07 --overwrite npartitions=2 distance_step=1.0 lat=MNEcomplet.lat long=MNEcomplet.lon
```

==> between 56 sec and 1min7s

npartitions are different on the 2 examples (I have no choice), but this parameter has not a big impact on the computing time.

Does anyone have an idea why it has this behavior?

---

Testing on Grass 6.4, using horizons allows me to decrease computation time from 42-50s to 32s.

Another question is: Is there a possibility to avoid the computation of the sun angles for each cell ?

Providing a single value for the whole area would be ok for me, and I can compute it by myself

Comment: Hi again Pierre, just for information, `npartitions` option was not working for shadow computation on grass6.x.  Have you tried without using it ?